# Changing h:datatable cell color or style dynamically in JSF

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a datatable where I want to change the color of a cell based on some analysis that is run on the contents. The table is linked to an array of Comment objects, which I have given a String cssClass that gets updated once the analysis is run. This is what I have tried plugging into the rowClasses property of the datatable. It's not working and I think the issue may be that I cannot access the variable created for each row of the datatable, from inside the datatable declaration.

Datatable code:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{post.comments}" var="comment" class="hs-table" rowClasses="#{comment.cssClass}" >
             <h:column>
                   #{comment.name}
             </h:column>
             <h:column>
                   #{comment.email}
             </h:column>
             <h:column>
                   #{comment.msg}
             </h:column>
 </h:dataTable>
```

The Comment class:

```
public class Comment {
private String msg;
private String email;
private String name;
private Date date;
private String cssClass;

public Comment(){
    cssClass = "normColumn";
}
epublic String getCssClass() {
    return cssClass;
}

public void setCssClass(String cssClass) {
    this.cssClass = cssClass;
}
```

}

Where the cssClass is updated in the managed bean:

```
if(tone>0)
            c.setCssClass("commentPos");
        else if(tone<0)
            c.setCssClass("commentNeg");
```

The class never gets assigned. Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the standard JSF `<h:dataTable>` component, the `rowClasses` attribute is unfortunately not evaluated on a per-row basis. It's evaluated on a per-table basis. Component libraries like Tomahawk and PrimeFaces however support the kind of attribute which you're looking for on their `<t:dataTable>` and `<p:dataTable>`.

With the standard JSF `<h:dataTable>` component you need to supply a comma-separated string of all row classes. This can look something like this:

```
public String getRowClasses() {
    StringBuilder rowClasses = new StringBuilder();

    for (Comment comment : comments) {
        if (rowClasses.length() > 0) rowClasses.append(",");
        rowClasses.append(comment.getCssClass());
    }

    return rowClasses.toString();
}
```

which is then to be referenced as

```html
<h:dataTable ... rowClasses="#{post.rowClasses}">
```

#### See also:

- [`<h:dataTable>` tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/dataTable.html) - lists all attributes and the accepted values